# Problem working with plugin in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3, gigya

I am trying to use Gigya_Social_Network_CakePHP_Plugin. I have installed cake 1.3 and and download the plugin to /app/plugins/Gigya. I added Gigya.Gigya in my helpers array. I get error that gigya helper is missing in the app/helpers folder.

I am not fully aware of how to include a plugin in a controller.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem was the installing the plugin.

The plugin should be placed ion the /app/plugins folder

And name should all be lowercase.

You can check if the plugin is installed correctly by logging onto

www.yourwebsite.com/plugin_folder_name/controller_name/action if this page shows up as missing controller. Then the setup is wrong.

I hope this helps somebody someday.

Comment: Bro, your wish is granted. Also, next time you should try wishing for a pile of money, or a house in Paris. I mean, just a thought, amiright?